# Full HD full FPS webcam

Tags: webcam

I would like to buy full HD resolution and full FPS (at least 25 FPS) at full resolution WEBCAM.  Or 'someothercam' that can be USB connected and not highly priced.

By full HD I don't mean 1920x1080 (that would be SF in this days) - I would be happy with device that could deliver full PAL resolution, at least 720x576.

Comment: You mean "high resolution", not "full HD resolution". Full HD can only mean one thing: 1920x1080.

Comment: Well, I think it should be, but not **always** a friend had a "full HD" Sony camcorder that recorded at 1920x900 or something just off of full hd... annoying and he hated me after I showed him!

Comment: I just added HD so I could easily explain what I need.  HD in context of webcams is everything above 320x240 :)

Comment: Thanks for accepting mine as the answer - just a bit of info for you - I went to a Microsoft event yesterday and saw this for real - it is excellent (although the frame rate didn't appear excellent in live viewing, but I guess if recording it would be higher). It has a really fast and good auto focus so if you hold text up against it at different distances, it looks very clear! I love itand may get one for myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently read the Microsoft now have a webcam that can do 1280 x 720 at 30 Frames per second.

[Here is the link to a review](http://www.engadget.com/2009/08/18/microsofts-lifecam-cinema-hd-webcam-lets-you-film-those-youtube/)... I see your profile shows Croatia, I know no shops there so you will have to Google the product name - "Microsoft LifeCam Cinema HD webcam"

Answer (score 0):

The company "Life Size", which was recently acquired by Logitech, sells HD cameras that are capable of full 720p30 over a 1MBps connection

http://www.lifesize.com/

Answer (score 0):

Since 2013, there are some webcams using H.264 encoding to deliver 30fps FullHD (1920x1080 pixles) video over USB 2.0. The Logitech C920 for example providing this is still sold today.